# How to use multiple And conditions in SQL Where clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am making a dynamic website in which people can search donors.
I am building my search page using php and mysqli.
I used SQL where clause to get input.

```
Select customusername, phonenumber
FROM users
WHERE country = ‘$country’ AND bgroup = ‘$bggroup’
  AND state = ‘$state’ AND district = ‘$district’
```

The values are brought properly from the form and I verified it with another clause.

But I could not get any thing from my database and it is throwing a fatal error.
And showing wrong query.
All my server connections are good and properly connected to database and table.
I know php code does not work in github to provide a source code for you I had uploaded in it
Please check my code  https://github.com/iblood/iblood.github.io/blob/master/demo.php
Please observe any mistakes in it and please solve my question
I have my own hosting so I provided above code
I am new to this field and stack overflow can any one of you please help me in solving this problem.

Thanking you advance

Comment: try first with a simple/unfiltered query and then add the where conditions

Comment: what's the error you're getting?

Comment: The error is it is not showing any data from database

Comment: Make sure you have data in your table that fits your query. Also make sure you are using the correct values in your query (`bgroup=‘$bggroup’` - should `$bggroup` be `$bgroup`?). Print your query to the screen and run it in phpMyAdmin/MySQL to make sure there actually _are_ results to be returned. Please post the code you use

Comment: Yes the data fits to it and I verified it with other queries

Comment: Not showing any data is not an error. What is the error message?

Comment: And see about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Comment: Also, you appear to be using smart quotes. Do not use Word to format code.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result  - all as formatted text, not images.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$sql = "Select 
     `customusername`,
     `phonenumber`
FROM `users`
WHERE
      `country` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $country)."'
      AND `bgroup` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $bggroup)."'
      AND `state` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $state)."'
     AND `district` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $disctrict)."'";
```

try this way, fields are inputs or dropdowns, if they are inputs, how u will be sure that user enter valid information?

Edited:
try this one, it's not tested, but it should work. Also please read [psr-2 coding style](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/)

```
if (isset($sqcountry) && mb_strlen($sqcountry)) {
    $search[] = " `country` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($searchconn, $sqcountry)."'";
}
if (isset($sqbgroup) && mb_strlen($sqbgroup)) {
    $search[] = " `bgroup` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($searchconn, $sqbgroup)."'";
}
if (isset($sqstate) && mb_strlen($sqstate)) {
    $search[] = " `sqstate` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($searchconn, $sqstate)."'";
}
if (isset($sqdistrict) && mb_strlen($sqdistrict)) {
    $search[] = " `district` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($searchconn, $sqdistrict)."'";
}
$where = '';
if (count($search)) {
    foreach($search as $value) {
        if (!mb_strlen($where)) {
            $where .= 'WHERE ' . $value;
            continue;
        }
        $where .= ' AND ' . $value;
    }
}

$sql = "SELECT 
            customusername,
            phonenumber
        FROM donors
        ".$where."
        LIMIT ${offset}, ${total_no_of_pages}";
$searchresult = mysqli_query($searchconn, $sql);
```

Comment: But no change in the result.  I had added my source code link to you please go through that

Comment: yes, I edited my answer please check right now and see what will happen